# Nothing heppend when i update table with html source code on MySql through tinymce

Tags: php, mysql, tinymce

I am trying to update a table in MySql though tinymce editor.
When I try to update by HTML source code nothing happens, but when I try with text only everything is fine.

Here's the html forms :

```
<?php
// ===========
require_once ('../../connect_pages.php');

// select HVAC Works
$select_hvac_works="SELECT * FROM works";
$select_res_hvac_works=mysqli_query($con,$select_hvac_works);
$get_data3=mysqli_fetch_assoc($select_res_hvac_works);

?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <script type="text/javascript" src="tinymce/tinymce.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    tinymce.init({
    selector: "textarea",
    //language: 'de',
    object_resizing: false,
    style_formats: [
    {title: 'Headline', block: 'h4', styles: {color: 'black'}},
    {title: 'Text', block: 'p', styles: {color: 'black'}},
    ],
    plugins: [
        "advlist autolink lists link image charmap print preview anchor",
        "searchreplace visualblocks code fullscreen",
        "insertdatetime media table contextmenu paste hr"
    ],
    toolbar: "code | fontselect | fontsizeselect | insertfile undo redo | styleselect | bold italic | alignleft aligncenter alignright alignjustify | bullist numlist outdent indent | link image | hr",
    menu: "|",
    height: "300px",
    resize: true,
    });
</script>
    </head>
<div class="row">
    <div id="breadcrumb" class="col-md-12 changefont">
        <ol class="breadcrumb" dir="rtl">
            <li><a>الرئيسية</a></li>
            <li><a>المنتجات</a></li>
            <li><a>تعديل</a></li>
        </ol>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12">
        <div class="box">

<div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-8">
        <div class="box">
            <div class="box-header">
                <div class="box-name">
                    <i class="fa fa-file"></i>
                    <span class="add" dir="ltr">Services - HVAC Works</span>
                </div>
                <div class="box-icons">
                </div>
                <div class="no-move"></div>
            </div>
            <div class="box-content">
                <form id="defaultForm" method="post" action="*" class="form-horizontal">
                    <fieldset>
                        <legend class="changefont">تفاصيل الصفحة</legend>
                            <div class="form-group">
                            <label class="col-sm-3 control-label changefont" dir="rtl">محتوى الصفحة</label>
                            <div class="col-sm-5" style="width:70% !important;" dir="rtl">
                                <textarea type="text" class="form-control changefont-f" style="width: 426px; height: 141px;" name="works"><?php echo $get_data3['content']; ?></textarea>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </fieldset>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <div class="col-sm-9 col-sm-offset-3">
                            <input style="float:left;margin-left:16%;font-weight:bold;font-size:14px;" name="edit_hvac_works" type="submit" class="btn btn-primary changefont" value="تعديل">
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </form>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

<script type="text/javascript">
// Run Select2 plugin on elements
function DemoSelect2(){
    $('#s2_with_tag').select2({placeholder: "Select OS"});
    $('#s2_country').select2();
}
// Run timepicker
function DemoTimePicker(){
    $('#input_time').timepicker({setDate: new Date()});
}
$(document).ready(function() {
    // Create Wysiwig editor for textare
    TinyMCEStart('#wysiwig_simple', null);
    TinyMCEStart('#wysiwig_full', 'extreme');
    // Add slider for change test input length
    FormLayoutExampleInputLength($( ".slider-style" ));
    // Initialize datepicker
    $('#input_date').datepicker({setDate: new Date()});
    // Load Timepicker plugin
    LoadTimePickerScript(DemoTimePicker);
    // Add tooltip to form-controls
    $('.form-control').tooltip();
    LoadSelect2Script(DemoSelect2);
    // Load example of form validation
    LoadBootstrapValidatorScript(DemoFormValidator);
    // Add drag-n-drop feature to boxes
    WinMove();
});
</script>
```

and here's my update processes php page - the problem occurs only with the table 'edit_havc_works':

```
<?php
//======== Connect ======//
require_once ('../../../connect_pages.php');
//======== Get Value ======//

$works = $_POST['works'];
//======== Get Value ======//

// ++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++ //


//========  ======//
if($_POST['edit_hvac_works']){

$update_hvac_works="update works set content='$works'";
mysqli_query($con,$update_hvac_works);
$done_update= "تم اضافة الصورة بنجاح! يمكنك معاينتها في قسم الصور والفيديو او الذهاب للموقع مباشرة.";
}
//======== ======//
// ++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++ //

echo "<meta http-equiv='refresh' content='14;url='>";
mysqli_close($con);
?>
```

When I try it on my localhost it works, but when I try it on my hosting site it fails.

Comment: Is this one really correct `$update_hvac_works="update works set content='$works'";`? Shouldn't it be `$update_hvac_works="update hvac_works set content='$works'";` or something? Not sure how the other querys look though.

Comment: You should really use prepared statements for this one. It should fix all your escaping related issues.

Comment: daxro : the name of the table in database is "Works" also as a i said when i update with text everything fine ! , thanks a lot.

Comment: apokryfo : thanks a lot .. of caurse it's better but now i have problem i don't what it is ! it's drive me crazy really .. i spend a more than day and half trying to figure it out !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on your following statement,

> when i try to update by HTML source code nothing happen .. but when i try with text only everything fine!.

I assume that your problem is escaping your input.

You should do something like this for your update:

```
<?php
require_once ('../../../connect_pages.php');

if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
  die("Connect error" . mysqli_connect_error());
}  


$works = $_POST['works'];

if($_POST['edit_hvac_works']){

$update_hvac_works="update works set content=?";
if ($stmt = mysqli_prepare($con,$update_hvac_works)) {
    $stmt->bind_param("s",$works);
    $stmt->execute();
} else {
    die("Statement creation error: ".mysqli_error($con));
}
$done_update= "تم اضافة الصورة بنجاح! يمكنك معاينتها في قسم الصور والفيديو او الذهاب للموقع مباشرة.";
}

echo "<meta http-equiv='refresh' content='14;url='>";
mysqli_close($con);
?>
```

Comment: thanks a lot , when i try .. it gave me " Fatal error: Call to a member function bind_param() on a non-object in /add.php on line 41 "

Comment: Based on your latest update, I've added some error checking. Check what is happening and let me know.

Comment: thanks you very much for trying to help me , appreciated .. same problem :  Fatal error: Call to a member function execute() on a non-object in /add.php on line 44

Comment: My bad. Try again.

Comment: how i can thanks you?! You saved my life !! .. thanks a lot appreciated a lot !!!